# ChangeTracker TrackGraph on list of object not tracked

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core

I'm trying to save list of object to Database with Entity framework Core and have a problem with saving large number of entities.
First I fetch list of entities of one type from database. Example:

```
class Event{
 int data1;
 int data2;
 ... 
 int data14;
 DateTime timestamp;
 long selectionId; //is null while fetching
}
```

I have a list of Event
Then i compute them and get list of object containing previous event
Example:

```
class Selection {
 int someData;
 int someData2;
 ...
 int someData5;
 List<Event> events
}
```

So events are object already exist in db but selection are create and i want to save them and update acording event field with only selectionId

What I did:

1 Approach:

I fetch list of events asNoTracking() from DB and compute them to get
a list of Selection also as noTracking containing lists of events. Then I _context.Selection.UpdateRange(selectionsList) (this happens very fast) and this is ok, it is saving and update, but update sql statement contains all field for events, but i want update only one field. I know why is happening so because all fields of event are marked as modified

2 Approach:

Second approach was to tracking fetched events but it slower than updating all fields when events weren't tracked by ef(first approach). It is generating good sql statement(only true changed properties are update).

3 Approach:

I tried to mark only changed fields of event object as modified but it is so slow. I got good sql statement(only true changed properties are update) but changing field by field property state is very very very slow for large event list

EXAMPLE CODE:

1 Approach:

```
    SaveSelectionCycles(SelectionCycles selectionCycles){

         _context.SelectionCycles.UpdateRange(selections);

         await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
     }
```

3 Approach:

```
SaveSelectionCycles(SelectionCycles selectionCycles){

_context.SelectionCycles.UpdateRange(selectionCycles);


foreach(SelectionCycle sc in selectionCycles){

            foreach(Event ev in eventToSave){
                _context.Entry(ev).Property("MaskedValue").IsModified = true;
                _context.Entry(ev).Property("SelectionCycleId").IsModified = true;
                _context.Entry(ev).Property("AvgWindow").IsModified = true;
                _context.Entry(ev).Property("Filtered").IsModified = true;
            }
        }


        await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
}
```

Expectations:

I want to change tracking for list of object and child entities but in fast way not by _context.Entry(ev).Property("AvgWindow").IsModified

Is there a way of doing that maybe with _context.ChangeTracker.TrackGraph but I dont know how to use it with list of object